# Filter array within array using single key = single value and single key = multiple value

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
const personData = {
  personID: 1234567,
  personList: [{
      name: ['name1', 'name2'],
      address: false,
      pin: 12345
    },
    {
      name: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
      address: true,
      pin: 45678
    },
    {
      name: ['name1'],
      address: false,
      pin: 12345
    },
  ]
};

const keys = ['name', 'address', 'pin']
const values = ['name1', 'name2', false, 12345]

let personDataArr = personData.personList.filter(function(e) {
  return keys.every(function(a) {
    return e[a] &&
      e[a].length > 0 ? values.every(x => e[a].includes(x)) : values.includes(e[a])
  });
});

console.log(personDataArr);
```

The code shows the person Data object which includes the information like name, address and pin.

I tried using `filter` but I am not getting a properly filtered result.

I am executing the code I am getting null, but I am expecting the first person List object.

Could some one take a look into the code and modify if possible and send me the expected result as output.

Comment: what is the expected result?

Comment: First personList object.

Comment: @Sammy you can check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55750220/9624435)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to have your `key value` as an `object` instead of two different arrays

```js
const {personList} = {personID: 1234567,personList: [{name: ['name1', 'name2'],address: false,pin: 12345},{name: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],address: true,pin: 45678},{name: ['name1'],address: false,pin: 12345},]};

const filterBy = { name:['name1', 'name2'],address: false,pin:12345 }

let personDataArr = personList.filter(e => {
  return Object.keys(e).every(key => {
    return Array.isArray(e[key]) ? filterBy[key].every(value=> e[key].includes(value)) 
                                 : e[key] === filterBy[key]
  })
})
console.log(personDataArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

It will get really hard to reliably filter with the filter criteria you've provided. How should the code determine which of the values are needed for every given key? Not possible.

It'll be better to provide the values in a well structured way, such as

```
const filterCriteria = [
  {
    key: 'name',
    values: ['name1', 'name2']
  }, {
    key: 'address',
    value: false
  }, {
    key: 'pin',
    value: 12345
  }
];
```

```js
const getPerson = (list, criterias) =>
  list.filter(element =>
    criterias.every(criteria =>
      element.hasOwnProperty(criteria.key) &&
      criteria.hasOwnProperty('value') ? 
        element[criteria.key] === criteria.value :
        (criteria.values.every(value => element[criteria.key].includes(value))) && element[criteria.key].every(value => criteria.values.includes(value)))
  );

console.log(getPerson(personData.personList, filterCriteria));
```

```html
<script>
const personData = {
  personID: 1234567,
  personList: [
    {
      name: ['name1', 'name2'],
      address: false,
      pin: 12345
    },
    {
      name: ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
      address: true,
      pin: 45678
    },
    {
      name: ['name1'],
      address: false,
      pin: 12345
    },
  ]
};

const filterCriteria = [
  {
    key: 'name',
    values: ['name1', 'name2']
  }, {
    key: 'address',
    value: false
  }, {
    key: 'pin',
    value: 12345
  }
];
</script>
```